# Modelling Task Completion Data

Tags: curve-fitting, censoring

I have a two dimensional dataset - the first variable ($t$) represents time, and the second ($y$) is bounded between 0 and 1:

- Think of $y$ as percentage completion of a task.
- $y$ is dependent on $t$ - as $t$ increases, $y$ is expected to increase as well, until it reaches a saturation value (not necessarily 1). (conversely, $y$ is not expected to decrease as $t$ increases)
- The observations of $y$ are obtained when the task attempt ends (which defines the $t$ observation). If more time was spent, $y$ would be larger - so the data is censored in a sense.
- There are a large number of observations with $y=0$. (>98% of the dataset)
- Most observations are at small values of $t$ (i.e. majority of task attempt times are short)

I am trying to capture the relation between $y$ and $t$ via a curve.

- What kind of method could I use here? I am not necessarily looking for a rigorous approach - even some simple heuristic would be helpful.
- Optionally, I would also like to incorporate the different levels of importance each observation has. So essentially I have some weights ($w$) associated with each data point.

Example of how the dataset looks like:

```
t  y    w
1  0.0  1
5  0.0  4
4  0.1  2
25 0.9  1
21 1.0  5
30 0.0  10
...
```